# Second derivative of the Christoffel symbols in normal coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

According to wikipedia the Taylor expansion of the Christoffel symbols of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ in normal coordinates is given by
$$
{\Gamma^{\lambda}}_{\mu\nu}(x)= -\frac 13 (R_{\lambda\nu\mu\tau}(0)+R_{\lambda\mu\nu\tau}(0))x^\tau+ O(|x|^2).
$$
Is there any reference for the calculation of the $O(|x|^2)$ term?
I did the computations as Yuval proposed and ended up with
$$
6\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_v} \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_w}{\Gamma^{n}}_{ij}(x) 
\\= \frac 12 g^{nl}
\left( \nabla_i R_{jvwl} + \nabla_i R_{jwvl} +\nabla_w R_{jivl} + \nabla_v R_{jiwl} + \nabla_w R_{jvil} + \nabla_v R_{jwil} \right) +
\left( \nabla_j R_{ivwl} + \nabla_j R_{iwvl} +\nabla_w R_{ijvl} + \nabla_v R_{ijwl} + \nabla_w R_{ivjl} + \nabla_v R_{iwjl} \right) -
\left( \nabla_l R_{ivwj} + \nabla_l R_{iwvj} +\nabla_w R_{ilvj} + \nabla_v R_{ilwj} + \nabla_w R_{ivlj} + \nabla_v R_{iwlj} \right)
$$
If I apply the symmetries of the curvature tensor
$$
\left( \nabla_i R_{jvwl} + \nabla_i R_{jwvl}  + 2\nabla_w R_{jvil} + 2\nabla_v R_{jwil} \right) +
\left( \nabla_j R_{ivwl} + \nabla_j R_{iwvl}   + 2\nabla_w R_{ivjl} + 2\nabla_v R_{iwjl} \right) -
\left( \nabla_l R_{ivwj} + \nabla_l R_{iwvj}  \right)
$$
I feel like the derivatives involving derivatives in $i,j,l$ should somehow cancel out with the Bianchi identities but I don't get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

This needs some computations involving the Jacobi field ODE. You just need an Taylor expansion for $g_{ij}$ since $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ involves $g$ and its
first derivative. See

John Lee & Thomas Parker "Yamabe Problem", Bull. AMS. vol 17. no 1 (1987),
see page 60-61, especially equation (54).

or

Schoen & Yau "Lectures on Differential Geometry", p210-211. You can use (3.4) there to compute the $O(|x|^2)$ term.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried doing it but its somewhat hard to verify the computations.